# CSS Hover Images

Tags: css, image, hover

I'm working on a site for some old guys who love cars. They're previous photo gallery is no longer in service and they asked me if I could make a new one. I wanted it as simple as I could make it. And so I made a table of images, that are small. Once you hover the mouse over an image it becomes larger, these guys told me they liked my idea. If you click on the image it will go straight to the image URL.

The problem is the transition from the original size to the larger one makes this glitchy look over the hover. I would like the transition to be smoother, any suggestions?

Here's the link to the site - http://tcrgv8club.org/photogallery.php

Here's my CSS code:

```
.model img{
width: 125px;
height: 100px;
border: 2px solid black;
z-index: 0;  
}

img:hover  {
width: 500px;
height: 450px;
z-index:1;
position: absolute;
}

.model td{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into the CSS `transition` property?

Comment: I added the webkit for a transition, but I still get some goofy stuff going from one picture to a different one. Cool stuff though!

Comment: It looks like there is transition applied already. He is talking about it looking like it is glitching and that is because when you hover image gets larger and moves down because its absolute positioning. So you are not hovering over it. Set your image hover to position relative and see how it is behaving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `transform: scale` as changing width/height will break your layout flow.

```css
.model img {
  width: 125px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
  transition: z-index 0s, transform 0.5s;
}
img:hover {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(2.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="model">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
img.thumbnail {
    max-width:20%;
    max-height:50%;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s, height 2s, transform 0.5s;
}
img.thumbnail:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(2);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(2);
    /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(2);
    /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(2);
    /* Opera */
    transform:scale(2);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raskarvishal7/1n3sebtc/)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the position to relative solved it for me, I'm sure the other answers would of worked as well. I'll see what the guys think. Thank you all!

```
.model img{
    width: 125px;
    height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
    z-index: 0;
-webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s;
transition: width 2s, height 2s;
}

img:hover  {
width: 550px;
height: 450px;
z-index:1;
position: relative;
}

.model td{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Otherwise this answer doesnt change the layout of the table, which I preffered the best.

```
.model img {
  width: 125px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
  transition: z-index 0s, transform 0.5s;
}
img:hover {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(2.5);
}
```